# split apply recombine, plyr, data.table in R

Tags: r, split, plyr, data.table, apply

I am doing the classic split-apply-recombine thing in R. My data set is a bunch of firms over time.  The applying I am doing is running a regression for each firm and returning the residuals, therefore, I am not aggregating by firm.  `plyr` is great for this but it takes a very very long time to run when the number of firms is large.  Is there a way to do this with `data.table`?

Sample Data:

```
dte, id, val1, val2
2001-10-02, 1, 10, 25
2001-10-03, 1, 11, 24
2001-10-04, 1, 12, 23
2001-10-02, 2, 13, 22
2001-10-03, 2, 14, 21
```

I need to split by each id (namely 1 and 2). Run a regression, return the residuals and append it as a column to my data. Is there a way to do this using `data.table`?

Comment: Are you sure the time suck is in the looping and not the regressions?

Comment: I'm sure it _is_ possible. How far have you gotten so far in implementing a **data.table** solution?

Comment: @blindJesse, unfortunately it is. i have not started implementing a solution. I wanted to see first if there was something that was standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing this needs to be sorted by "id" to line up properly. Luckily that happens automatically when you set the key:

```
dat <-read.table(text="dte, id, val1, val2
 2001-10-02, 1, 10, 25
 2001-10-03, 1, 11, 24
 2001-10-04, 1, 12, 23
 2001-10-02, 2, 13, 22
 2001-10-03, 2, 14, 21
 ", header=TRUE, sep=",")
 dtb <- data.table(dat)
 setkey(dtb, "id")
 dtb[, residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by="id"]
#---------------
cbind(dtb, dtb[, residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by="id"])
#---------------
            dte id val1 val2 id.1            V1
[1,] 2001-10-02  1   10   25    1  1.631688e-15
[2,] 2001-10-03  1   11   24    1 -3.263376e-15
[3,] 2001-10-04  1   12   23    1  1.631688e-15
[4,] 2001-10-02  2   13   22    2  0.000000e+00
[5,] 2001-10-03  2   14   21    2  0.000000e+00



> dat <- data.frame(dte=Sys.Date()+1:1000000, 
                    id=sample(1:2, 1000000, repl=TRUE),  
                    val1=runif(1000000),  val2=runif(1000000) )
> dtb <- data.table(dat)
> setkey(dtb, "id")
> system.time(  cbind(dtb, dtb[, residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by="id"]) )
   user  system elapsed 
  1.696   0.798   2.466 
> system.time( dtb[,transform(.SD,r = residuals(lm(val1~val2))),by = "id"] )
   user  system elapsed 
  1.757   0.908   2.690
```

**EDIT from Matthew** :
This is all correct for v1.8.0 on CRAN. With the small addition that `transform` in `j` is the subject of [data.table wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages%3acran%3adata.table) point 2: "For speed don't `transform()` by group, `cbind()` afterwards".  But, `:=` now works by group in v1.8.1 and is both simple and fast. See my answer for illustration (but no need to vote for it).

Well, I voted for it. Here is the console command to install v 1.8.1on a Mac (if you have the proper XCode tools avaialble, since it only there in source):

```
install.packages("data.table", repos= "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source", 
               lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/lib")
```

(For some reason I could not get the Mac GUI Package Installer to read r-forge as a repository.)

Comment: I'm curious, would there be a performance difference between this and `dtb[,transform(.SD,r = residuals(lm(val1~val2))),by = "id"]`?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. On 10,000 cases, they both take a tenth of a sec as elapsed. The run-to-run variation is bigger than the differences with 100,000 cases. (around .3 sec) . I'll post the 1MM record case.

Comment: @DWin, i did have a followup question that is somewhat unrelated: how does the `setkey()` function work in terms of being able to modify dtb without actually doing any assignment? I thought that once you pass something to a function and try to modify, a local copy gets created.

Comment: If you are asking about @joran's method, it's a special feature of data.table's version of "[", ".SD", and "transform". The ".SD" does a database-join of results of the transform-expression using the data.table to itself, and the transform does the equivalent of my "cbind" function. Neither one of the methods above actually changes "dtb" itself so you would need to do an assignment to some name, possibly "dtb", in order to preserve the results.

Comment: @DWin, i was actually asking about the `setkey` function in particular, not the actual answer. it modifies the data.table without any assignment. same thing with the `:=` operator that is built in to data.table... how does it do this without assignment?

Comment: @Alex Are you asking how it's implemented internally? Core parts of `data.table` are written in C, such as `setkey` and `:=`. From C you can modify by reference, if you are very careful.

Comment: @DWin This is a lot easier (and a lot faster) in v1.8.1 now that `:=` works by group. You don't need to sort first by id to line it up, and no need to `cbind` or `transform` (which both copy the whole dataset and are slow). But this answer is correct with v1.8.0 (as currently on CRAN).

Comment: @MatthewDowle, yes that is exactly what i was wondering about: how you could do things by reference in R. given that it's written in C, that makes perfect sense.  THank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

DWin's answer is correct for v1.8.0 (as currently on CRAN). But in v1.8.1 (on R-Forge repository), `:=` now works by group.  It works for non-contiguous groups too so there is no need to `setkey` first for it to line up.

```
dtb <- as.data.table(dat)
dtb
           dte id val1 val2
1:  2001-10-02  1   10   25
2:  2001-10-03  1   11   24
3:  2001-10-04  1   12   23
4:  2001-10-02  2   13   22
5:  2001-10-03  2   14   21
dtb[, resid:=residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by=id]
           dte id val1 val2         resid
1:  2001-10-02  1   10   25  1.631688e-15
2:  2001-10-03  1   11   24 -3.263376e-15
3:  2001-10-04  1   12   23  1.631688e-15
4:  2001-10-02  2   13   22  0.000000e+00
5:  2001-10-03  2   14   21  0.000000e+00
```

To upgrade to v1.8.1 just install from the R-Forge repo. (R 2.15.0+ is needed when installing any binary package from R-Forge) :

```
install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

or install from source if you can't upgrade to latest R.  `data.table` itself only needs R 2.12.0+.

Extending to the 1MM case :

```
DT = data.table(dte=Sys.Date()+1:1000000, 
                id=sample(1:2, 1000000, repl=TRUE),
                val1=runif(1000000),  val2=runif(1000000) )
setkey(DT, id)
system.time(ans1 <- cbind(DT, DT[, residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by="id"]) )
   user  system elapsed 
 12.272   0.872  13.182 
ans1
                dte id      val1       val2 id           V1
      1: 2012-07-02  1 0.8369147 0.57553383  1  0.336647598
      2: 2012-07-05  1 0.0109102 0.02532214  1 -0.488633325
      3: 2012-07-06  1 0.4977762 0.16607786  1 -0.001952414
     ---                                                   
 999998: 4750-05-27  2 0.1296722 0.62645838  2 -0.370627034
 999999: 4750-05-28  2 0.2686352 0.04890710  2 -0.231952238
1000000: 4750-05-29  2 0.9981029 0.91626787  2  0.497948275

system.time(DT[, resid:=residuals(lm(val1 ~ val2)), by=id])
   user  system elapsed 
  7.436   0.648   8.107 
DT
                dte id      val1       val2        resid
      1: 2012-07-02  1 0.8369147 0.57553383  0.336647598
      2: 2012-07-05  1 0.0109102 0.02532214 -0.488633325
      3: 2012-07-06  1 0.4977762 0.16607786 -0.001952414
     ---                                                
 999998: 4750-05-27  2 0.1296722 0.62645838 -0.370627034
 999999: 4750-05-28  2 0.2686352 0.04890710 -0.231952238
1000000: 4750-05-29  2 0.9981029 0.91626787  0.497948275
```

The example above only has 2 groups, is quite small at under 40MB, and `Rprof` shows 96% of the time is spent in `lm`. So in these cases `:=` by group is not for a speed advantage really, but more for the convenience; i.e., less code needed to write and no superfluous columns added to the output.  As size grows, the avoidance of copies comes into it and speed advantages start to show. Especially, `transform` in `j` will slow down terribly as the number of groups increases.

Comment: Thanks. Matthew. I am putting a note at the end of my answer that has the console command to install the new version from r-forge on a Mac.

Comment: @DWin Oh. I thought R-Forge builds a binary for Mac too and it was as simple as that. It has a build log for Mac [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240) then click 'show/hide' button. You do have to be 2.15.0+ for R-Forge repo, though, I keep forgetting to mention that.

Comment: @DWin which might also explain why Mac GUI Package Installer didn't recognise R-Forge (if it is 2.14), since the repo is 2.15+ only.

Comment: That could be it... but I do have a successfully compiled version with R 2.14.2 now. Hasn't been tested in the heat of battle, though.

Comment: @Dwin Great, it needs a fight or two. `:=` by group was a big internal change so I wouldn't be surprised if there are some wrinkles left. It has got past quite a few heavy users though, so if anything it'll be edge cases now rather than basic faults. Touch wood.