# Avoiding `foreach` by using `data.table`: error "Combining := in j with by is not yet implemented"

Tags: r, foreach, data.table

I had created a function a couple of weeks ago using the library `foreach`. This function finds the  previous month's market capitalisation the companies in my dataset. Since this dataset is very large, I am trying to rewrite this function using `data.table` only (getting rid of `foreach` altogether), but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Here is what I have: my data.table object contains (among others columns) a column with an integer specifying the current month (TM), the company number (PERMNO), the market capitalisation at the end of that month (MKTCAP) and a column with an integer for the previous month (PM). Here is a summary of the table for the year 1962:

```
> summary(results62)
       TM             PERMNO          MKTCAP                PM        
 Min.   :196201   Min.   :10006   Min.   :      41   Min.   :196112  
 1st Qu.:196205   1st Qu.:18382   1st Qu.:   11462   1st Qu.:196204  
 Median :196208   Median :24328   Median :   37367   Median :196207  
 Mean   :196207   Mean   :24349   Mean   :  215224   Mean   :196201  
 3rd Qu.:196210   3rd Qu.:29866   3rd Qu.:  132181   3rd Qu.:196209  
 Max.   :196212   Max.   :86239   Max.   :31349066   Max.   :196211  
                                                     NA's   :25
```

(here 196201 means 1962-JAN, for example)

To get me started, I created a new object with data for company PERMNO = 10006

```
> data1006 <- results62[PERMNO == 10006,]
> data10006
          TM PERMNO    MKTCAP     PM
 [1,] 196201  10006 104171.00 196112
 [2,] 196202  10006 104527.75 196201
 [3,] 196203  10006  97036.00 196202
 [4,] 196204  10006 102565.62 196203
 [5,] 196205  10006  85263.25 196204
 [6,] 196206  10006  84193.00 196205
 [7,] 196207  10006  98077.50 196206
 [8,] 196208  10006  97532.62 196207
 [9,] 196209  10006  92265.50 196208
[10,] 196210  10006  98804.00 196209
[11,] 196211  10006 105887.38 196210
[12,] 196212  10006 112062.62 196211
```

then I created a column called LAGMKTCAP with NAs as placeholders

```
> data1006[,LAGMKTCAP := NA_real_]
```

To include the previous month market capitalisation for each observation I use

```
> data1006[,LAGMKTCAP := data1006$MKTCAP[match(data1006$PM,data1006$TM)]]
          TM PERMNO    MKTCAP      PM LAGMKTCAP
 [1,] 196201  10006 104171.00  196112        NA
 [2,] 196202  10006 104527.75  196201 104171.00
 [3,] 196203  10006  97036.00  196202 104527.75
 [4,] 196204  10006 102565.62  196203  97036.00
 [5,] 196205  10006  85263.25  196204 102565.62 
 [6,] 196206  10006  84193.00  196205  85263.25 
 [7,] 196207  10006  98077.50  196206  84193.00
 [8,] 196208  10006  97532.62  196207  98077.50
 [9,] 196209  10006  92265.50  196208  97532.62
[10,] 196210  10006  98804.00  196209  92265.50
[11,] 196211  10006 105887.38  196210  98804.00
[12,] 196212  10006 112062.62  196211 105887.38
```

which is perfect. Now I need to do this for each of the companies, using the whole dataset which contains thousands of companies. My best attempt was

```
> results62[,LAGMKTCAP := results62$MKTCAP[match(results62$PM,results62$TM)],by=PERMNO]
```

but I get the error

> Error in `[.data.table`(results62, , `:=`(LAGMKTCAP,
>   results62$MKTCAP[match(results62$PM,  :    Combining := in j with by
>   is not yet implemented. Please let maintainer('data.table') know if
>   you are interested in this.

I am not sure how to do this except by using `foreach`: I could create a vector with the unique numbers of companies and iterate this as follows:

```
conumb <- unique(results62$PERMNO)

lag.mkt.cap <- function(results62){
results62$MKTCAP[match(results62$PM,results62$TM)]
}

lagmktcap <- foreach(i=1:length(conumb),.combine=c) %do% lag.mkt.cap(results62[PERMNO == conumb[i],])
```

This is already a big improvement on my previous function (it takes 1/6 of the time), but I would really like to avoid using `foreach` and make the most of `data.table`. Any ideas?

PS: It might be helpful to use this example dataset which contains data for 3 companies spanning 4 months:

```
dataexample <- data.table(TM = c(196201L, 196202L, 196203L, 196204L, 196201L, 196202L, 196203L, 196204L, 196201L, 196202L, 196203L, 196204L), 
PERMNO = c(10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10014L, 10014L, 10014L, 10014L, 10030L, 10030L, 10030L, 10030L), 
MKTCAP = c(104171, 104527.75, 97036, 102565.625, 13290.75, 14499, 13693.5, 12485.25, 81600, 83232, 81600, 82416), 
PM = c(196112L, 196201L, 196202L, 196203L, 196112L, 196201L, 196202L, 196203L, 196112L, 196201L, 196202L, 196203L))
```

Comment: I guess I should say that there are missing observations and I can't simply get the previous line's market capitalisation.

Comment: FYI `:=` is implemented in version 1.81 which is hosted on r-forge. @matthew dowle outlines that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279304/split-apply-recombine-plyr-data-table-in-r/11284018#11284018)

Comment: #*@$#! It works, it works!!! I want to jump and scream and kiss Matthew! @Chase, what do you say? Post your comment as an answer? My problem is solved....

Comment: Hah! Awesome. I'm sure matt will appreciate the good internet karma. Feel free to answer your own question, all I did was point you in the right direction :)

Comment: @Chase but that's the answer! The line of code I used is the one I have in my question, so really, I didn't have anything other than install the new version and retry the steps above. I don't want to delete the question because who knows? It might be useful for some google user in the future.

Comment: :-) Vivi, you may have just topped @DavyKavanagh's comment that I used to open the recent [LondonR talk](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/LondonR_2012.pdf)! Yes answering your own question is encouraged on S.O. Also if you could click the 'i use it!' button on Crantastic [here](http://crantastic.org/packages/data-table) that really helps encourage us (and other packages you use too).