# How do I apply a "patch" to a data.frame?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

For lack of a better word, how do I apply a "patch" to a R data.frame? Suppose I have a master database with firm and outlet columns and an ownership shares variable that is 1 or 0 in this example, but could be any percentage.

```
// master
     firm outlet shares.pre
1    five      1          0
2     one      1          1
3     red      1          0
4  yellow      1          0
5    five      2          0
6     one      2          0
// many more
```

I want to let firm "one" sell outlet "1" to firm "red", which transaction I have in another data.frame

```
// delta
  firm outlet shares.delta
1  one      1         -1
2  red      1          1
```

What is the most efficient way in R to apply this "patch" or transaction to my master database? The end result should look like this:

```
// preferably master, NOT a copy
     firm outlet shares.post
1    five      1          0
2     one      1          0  <--- was 1
3     red      1          1  <--- was 0
4  yellow      1          0
5    five      2          0
6     one      2          0
// many more
```

I am not particular about keeping the suffixes `pre`, `post` or `delta`. If they were all named `shares` that would be fine too, I simply want to "add" these data frames.

**UPDATE**: my current approach is this

```
update <- (master$firm %in% delta$firm) & (master$outlet %in% delta$outlet)
master[update,]$shares <- master[update,]$shares + delta$shares
```

Yes, I'm aware it does a vector scan to creat the Boolean `update` vector, and that the subsetting is also not very efficient. But the thing I don't like about it most is that I have to write out the matching columns.

Comment: Efficient in terms of speed or code length?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman preferably both, but code length is more important (the database is about 100 lines long, it's a firm-level database, not a high-frequency stock market trading thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `data.table`. Assuming you've loaded both your data in `df1` and `df2` `data.frame`s,

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table(df2)
setkey(dt1, firm, outlet)
setkey(dt2, firm, outlet)
dt1 <- dt2[dt1]
dt1[is.na(dt1)] <- 0
dt1[, shares.post := shares.delta + shares.pre]

#      firm outlet shares.delta shares.pre shares.post
# 1:   five      1            0          0           0
# 2:   five      2            0          0           0
# 3:    one      1           -1          1           0
# 4:    one      2            0          0           0
# 5:    red      1            1          0           1
# 6: yellow      1            0          0           0
```

Comment: +1 tnx! Is there any way I can avoid creating an `out` copy of my original data frame? I would prefer to directly update `dt1`.

Comment: I like the `data.table` syntax, but I guess the assignment will scan over all entries of the master database? Is this more efficient than my current approach (see updated question)?

Comment: Nope. it's by reference. Read about `?':='` from the documentation. It reads `Fast add, remove and modify subsets of columns, by reference.`

Comment: Yes, this will be much much faster than your updated solution. Try benchmarking with `rbenchmark`. [**Here's a post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139586/how-to-optimize-subsetting-from-a-large-dataset/14140191#14140191) where you can get the idea of using `rbenchmark`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a more precise answer if you had provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but here's one way:

- Call your first data.frame `dat` and your second `chg`

Then you could merge the two:

```
dat <- merge(dat,chg)
```

And just subtract:

```
dat$shares <- with(dat, shares.pre + shares.delta )
```

Comment: +1 tnx! but this does not apply the changes to my orginal `dat`, how can I do that?